# Toggling and binding a boolean value with a checkbox in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, ember-data

I’m trying to toggle between a `true` and `false` value with a bound checkbox (`photoApproved`), but having no so luck in my controller code.

Here’s the `photos_controller.js`:

```
App.PhotosController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(

  photoApproved: ((key, value) ->
    model = @get("model")
    if value is 'undefined'
      model.get "approved"
    else
      model.set "approved", value
      model.save()
      value
  ).property("model.approved")

)
```

Here’s the `template` file `photos.hbs`:

```
<h1>Photos</h1>

<ul>
  {{#each controller}}
    <li class="masonry-brick">
      <h3>Approved: {{approved}}</h3>
      {{input type="checkbox" checked=photoApproved class="toggle"}}
      {{#link-to "photo" this}}{{name}}{{/link-to}}
      <img {{bind-attr src=image_url}} alt="Logo">
    </li>
  {{else}}
    <li>There are no photos.</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>

{{outlet}}
```

And finally, here’s the `model`:

```
App.Photo = DS.Model.extend(
  name: DS.attr("string")
  description: DS.attr("string")
  image_url: DS.attr("string")
  approved: DS.attr("boolean")
)
```

How should I change my photoApproved function to get things working properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ember 2.4 answer:

```
<input type="checkbox"
  checked="{{if info.show_in_email 'checked'}}"
  onclick={{action (mut info.show_in_email)
  value="target.checked"}} />
```

where `info` is a ember model and `show_in_email` is a boolean field.

Answer (score 3):

I notice 2 things:

`photoApproved` is a property of the collection, not of an individual model.

You should define an itemController for the `PhotosController` and define `photoApproved` in there:

```
App.PhotosController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(
  itemController: 'photo'
)

App.PhotoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(

  photoApproved: ((key, value) ->
    model = @get("model")
    if value is 'undefined'
      model.get "approved"
    else
      model.set "approved", value
      model.save()
      value
  ).property("model.approved")

)
```

Next, I don't see why you need to define `photoApproved` at all. When you use `approved` as checked value on the checkbox, it's already bound to the model.
You can then define an observer for saving the model (but I'm not sure if the following controller code is correct).

```
<li class="masonry-brick">
  <h3>Approved: {{approved}}</h3>
  {{input type="checkbox" checked=approved class="toggle"}}
  {{#link-to "photo" this}}{{name}}{{/link-to}}
  <img {{bind-attr src=image_url}} alt="Logo">
</li>

App.PhotoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(
  approvePhoto: (->
    @get('model').save() unless @get('approved')
  ).observes("approved")
)
```

Comment: Ah this looks like a much more elegant solution. Only problem is that the original approved value isn’t binding on load — they’re all false by default. Also, when the checkbox is clicked, the PUT request in only fired on setting true. I need it to set on both.

Comment: Ah, solved: just removing the `unless @get('approved')` did the trick. Going to answer it in below.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing the `unless @get('approved')` on the `approvePhoto` function.

```
# controller
App.PhotoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(

  approvePhoto: ((key, value) ->
    @get('model').save()
  ).observes("model.approved")

)

# template
<li class="masonry-brick">
  <h3>Approved: {{approved}}</h3>
  {{input type="checkbox" checked=approved class="toggle"}}
  {{#link-to "photo" this}}{{name}}{{/link-to}}
  <img {{bind-attr src=image_url}} alt="Logo">
</li>
```

Comment: Cool. You can even remove `model.` from the observe method.